# Sum operation on PySpark DataFrame giving TypeError when type is fine

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have such DataFrame in PySpark (this is the result of a take(3), the dataframe is very big):

```
sc = SparkContext()
df = [Row(owner=u'u1', a_d=0.1), Row(owner=u'u2', a_d=0.0), Row(owner=u'u1', a_d=0.3)]
```

the same *owner* will have more rows. What I need to do is summing the values of the field a_d per owner, after grouping, as

```
b = df.groupBy('owner').agg(sum('a_d').alias('a_d_sum'))
```

but this throws error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

However, the schema contains double values, not strings (this comes from a printSchema()):

```
root
|-- owner: string (nullable = true)
|-- a_d: double (nullable = true)
```

So what is happening here?

Comment: are you sure that all your lines are fine? I mean, did you check that all rows have a valid a_d value?

Comment: @mark91 the a_d field comes from a multiplication of two double columns in another dataframe, I see no way it could be a string. Is there a way I could check this?

Comment: you can do something like getting the underlying RDD and filtering it using a RegExp on the field a_d.... Or you can write the result to a Hive table and look for NULLs in that column reading it through Hive... Or if you have a subset of few data which shows this problem you can even inspect it...

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You are not using the correct sum function but the `built-in` function `sum` (by default).

So the reason why the `build-in` function won't work is 
that's it takes an iterable as an argument where as here the name of the column passed is a string and the `built-in` function can't be applied on a string. [Ref. Python Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

You'll need to import the proper function from `pyspark.sql.functions` :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as _sum

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [Row(owner=u'u1', a_d=0.1), Row(owner=u'u2', a_d=0.0), Row(owner=u'u1', a_d=0.3)]
)

df2 = df.groupBy('owner').agg(_sum('a_d').alias('a_d_sum'))
df2.show()

# +-----+-------+
# |owner|a_d_sum|
# +-----+-------+
# |   u1|    0.4|
# |   u2|    0.0|
# +-----+-------+
```

Comment: what version of spark are you using ? because I can't reproduce the error unless it's the built-in function sum. Are you running it in pyspark or submitting your script ?

Comment: can you write `sum` in your pyspark and update with the output here ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, was convinced I had imported and I hadn't. Can you elaborate on why the built-in fails, where does it see a str?

Comment: how come online tutorials don't point this out? https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-groupby-agg-aggregate-explained/

Comment: How would I know ? I've been doing spark for 10 years, I don't read these tutorials :)