# Why does pyspark agg tell me that datatypes are incorrect here?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the folowing types:

```
>>> mydf.printSchema()
root
 |-- protocol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_port: long (nullable = true)
 |-- bytes: long (nullable = true)
```

And when I try to aggregate it like this:

```
df_agg = mydf.groupBy('protocol').agg(sum('bytes'))
```

I am being told:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Now, this does not make sense to me, since I see the types are fine for aggregation in `printSchema()` as you can see above.

So, I tried converting it to integer just incase:

```
mydf_converted = mydf.withColumn("converted",mydf["bytes_out"].cast(IntegerType()).alias("bytes_converted"))
```

but still failure:

```
my_df_agg_converted = mydf_converted.groupBy('protocol').agg(sum('converted'))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

How to fix it?  I looked at this question, but the fix did not help me at all - same issue:
[Sum operation on PySpark DataFrame giving TypeError when type is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719039/sum-operation-on-pyspark-dataframe-giving-typeerror-when-type-is-fine)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python is confused between its [built-in `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function and the pyspark aggregation `sum` function you want to use. So you're basically passing a string `'converted'` to the python built-in `sum` function which expects an iterable of int.

Try loading pyspark `functions` with an alias instead:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
my_df_agg_converted = mydf_converted.groupBy('protocol').agg(psf.sum('converted'))
```

This will tell it to use the `pyspark` function rather than the built in one.

Comment: oh gosh that's a terrible bug.  I'll try that thank you!!

Comment: It's not really a bug, one of the functions works with 'int' and you're passing it a string, the other one works with pyspark columns but can interpret strings. If you pass a pyspark column instead of a string it will also understand which function you want to use

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try converting it to string.

The first type is the one you are using, and the second type is the one it wants

Comment: But I am summing values and you cannot sum over strings, right?