# Streaming JSON data from Kafka into Pyspark: aggregation not working on the JSON data

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to read JSON data from Kafka into Spark using Python and then doing some aggregation operations on the data, but there is some problem. I have the following code:
First I just send the input data to the console:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0- 
10_2.11:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Total-spending-for-top-users")\
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "saurabmarjara2")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()


jsonschema = StructType([StructField("order_id", IntegerType()),
                StructField("customer_id", IntegerType()),
                StructField("taxful_total_price", IntegerType())])

mta_stream = df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), jsonschema) \
                        .alias("parsed_mta_values"))

mta_data = mta_stream.select("parsed_mta_values.*")

qry = mta_data.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
qry.awaitTermination()
```

### This works correctly. The output is:

| order_id | customer_id | taxful_total_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 937665 | 7 | 10 |
| 937666 | 3 | 4 |
| 937667 | 6 | 3 |
| 937668 | 4 | 4 |

But I want to perform aggregation on the data by grouping by the customer_id field and summing the taxful_total_price. This will give me the total spending for every customer.

Here are the changes I made to the code:

```
df2 = 
mta_data.groupBy("customer_id").agg(sum("taxful_total_price"). 
alias("total_spending"))

qry = df2.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
qry.awaitTermination()
```

This is the error I am getting:

File "sparkconsumer.py", line 31, in 
df2=mta_data.groupBy("customer_id").agg(sum("taxful_total_price").alias("total_spending"))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

I have specified that each of the columns are integer types in the jsonschema. I think this is a problem with:

```
mta_stream.select("parsed_mta_values.*")
```

I tried this:

```
 df2 = mta_data.groupBy( 
 "parsed_mta_values.customer_id").agg(sum( 
 "parsed_mta_values.taxful_total_price").alias("total_spending"))
```

But this gives the same error as above.

Please help!

Comment: Use pyspark function as opposed to python's builtin.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719760/2986344

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum operation on PySpark DataFrame giving TypeError when type is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719039/sum-operation-on-pyspark-dataframe-giving-typeerror-when-type-is-fine)